# How can I make my 3G router reset its connection in the middle of the night?

Tags: router, browser, automation, wifi-configuration

I have [a 3G router](http://web.archive.org/web/20160603204945/http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/?q=huawei-power-fi-e8221), which is my only internet connection. I pay per megabyte.

The router hosts WiFi. It is is not physically connected to the computer. It gets its power from an electric socket.

Sometimes I download large files. *Between midnight and 6 AM* downloading is 5.6 times cheaper (it costs 0.69 USD per GB.)

So I configure my download client to only download between midnight and 6 AM, no problem.

There is one problem, however. To get this cheap download rate, I buy a special pack from my 3G operator (Airtel India.) I can buy this pack before going to bed. But, in a rather silly design, this pack only becomes active if I disconnect from the network, and then reconnect. This has to be done *after midnight.* (I stayed up late one night to experiment.)

One way to achieve this is to turn the 3G router off and on again.

Another way is to simply press this (circled) button twice in the router's configuration interface.

[image]

But it has to be done *after midnight*, at which point I want to be sound asleep.

How can I configure my computer to do this automatically after midnight? Pick any OS and/or browswer you'd like. (Slight preference for OS X, though.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40550/discussion-on-question-by-fiksdal-how-can-i-make-my-3g-router-reset-its-connecti).

Answer (score 2):

Just buy an [electric timer](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=plug%20timers&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=88139420475&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12317061687285133106&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_6wo46poof5_b_p11).  These can be set/programmed to power cycle any electic device.